# how to fetch embed videos from facebook with its comments plugin?

Tags: php

i am fetching video from my facebook page through its i frame embed code on my website. but i also wants to fetch same videos comments plugin on my page. and when i comment on video through my web page. same comments shows on my facebook page inside videos comment plugin.  please help me that how i do this,

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=603836463000637" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Embed the Post so users can directly click to see the comments

> [image]

There is no other way to embed the comments that are already made on the Particular Video ON facebook.